# Open another process in another Window

Tags: python, terminal, multiple-processes

In my code I would like to launch a function/script in another python window (say, when you run one script, a back window pops up, I want that script to manage other scripts. They don't need to communicate).

Similar to multiprocessing but they have their own pop up windows and outputs. All their information is going to be written to a file there after.

I have searched a fair amount but it seems like no one want a script to run another script in another window, potentially running 4 or 5 python windows consecutively, each using a separate core.

Comment: have you tried using something like multi-threading with tkinter?

Comment: adding to @IlaiK i can suggest you using Celery

Comment: After taking a look at multithreading, I'm not sure that would help much. Essentially, all the scripts will be doing a lot of number crunching and there would be no time for those to run between each other.

I'll take a look at Celery and see if that's any different though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `os.startfile(filename)` Here is an example that runs another python file:

```
import os

os.startfile("File.py")

print("Started Running!")
```

This will open and run another python program, allowing this program to continue running.

Comment: Be aware that `os.startfile` only works on Windows. Furthermore, it doesn’t *execute* a file, it opens it with its associated application. For a Python file that might well be an editor or IDE, depending on how the system is configured.

Comment: This works perfectly! I did try os.start but not startfile! Thank you so much, you've saved me a massive headache!