# python command to open file in new window or module?

Tags: python

I've been using `exec(open().read())` in python IDE on linux to run the file but I want to open it in a separate/new window or tab. is there a specific parameter or a different function that I could use to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean - "to start a new process with your code from file"? Use standard multiprocessing if yes.

Comment: Assuming you want to literally open another file in another window for the visual appeal of having two windows (and not running another code snippet as a Daemon thread) you could use `os.popen()` to run an entirely new python interpeter process from your terminal which would subsequently mean a new window. This can be simplified in windows using `os.startfile()` which is explained further here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947701/open-another-process-in-another-window.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I'm not sure I understand the question. Please [edit] to add details. To start, what OS are you using/targeting? And you're talking about a terminal/console window, right? And what do you mean by "module"? It doesn't seem like you're talking about a Python [module](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module). Maybe you mean a **tab** or some graphical element like that? See [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: Also, `exec()` runs the other file in the existing runtime, so do you want that to copy over to the new window too? I'm not sure how that'd work exactly, it just seems like what you're trying to do. Ideally you'd make a [mre] showing exactly what you're currently doing and exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Basically looking for a linux equivalent to `os.startfile()` but can't find any, and popen gives the `<os._wrap_close object at 0x102ee5ab0>` while the doc says it's obsolete anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["open", 'filename.extension'])
```